# start ElasticSearch (v. 7.x) Testcontainer with SSL on Junit5

Tags: elasticsearch, integration-testing, junit5, testcontainers

I'm attempting to get a testcontainer running that is like the actual container, which runs on an TLS/SSL connection. I see that there's a way to do it on 8.0.0 (since it is enabled by default) but I have 7.17.x instead. I can't seem to figure out a way for it to run on HTTPS. This is how I'm starting the container (without TLS):

```
   public static ElasticsearchContainer container = new ElasticsearchContainer(
      DockerImageName.parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.3"))
      .withPassword("password");
```

I've tried to get the container to run on TLS by giving it the same settings as in our normal docker compose (i.e. all the `xpack.security.*` variables) but it doesn't seem to work. It either can't copy the cert files I want over or it tells me the keys/certs cannot be found (even with `.withCopyFileToContainer(...)`)

Should I even be trying to get it to run with TLS at all??

Edit: I think I fixed it?? But maybe there's a more elegant and less robust way of doing this.

```
   static final MountableFile mountableCrt = MountableFile.forClasspathResource("certs/elastic-node.crt");
   static final MountableFile mountableKey = MountableFile.forClasspathResource("certs/elastic-node.key");
   static final MountableFile mountableCa = MountableFile.forClasspathResource("certs/ca.crt");
   
   static Map<String, String> sslVars = Map.ofEntries(
         Map.entry("xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled", "true"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.http.ssl.key", "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-node.key"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate", "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-node.crt"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities", "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.crt"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode", "certificate"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", "true"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.transport.ssl.key", "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-node.key"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate", "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-node.crt"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities", "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.crt"),
         Map.entry("xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode", "certificate")
      );

public static ElasticsearchContainer container = new ElasticsearchContainer(
      DockerImageName.parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.3"))
      .withReuse(true)
      .withCopyFileToContainer(mountableKey, "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/")
      .withCopyFileToContainer(mountableCrt, "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/")
      .withCopyFileToContainer(mountableCa, "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/")
      .withCertPath("/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.crt")
      .withEnv(sslVars)
      .withPassword("password");

//rest client with https here
```

I had to put it specifically under config, I tried putting it elsewhere and it would fail?

Comment: Replicating what docker-compose does by using the variables and `withCopyFileToContainer` should work. Can you share logs of what goes wrong?